# Unhandled Exception: type '(String) => Null' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => dynamic)?'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created custom dropdown widget with label with generic type then when try to add onChnage like method whenever value change on my `onSelected` function should call and provide value but it's giving me an error i don't why everything seems to look fine even I have check dropdown widget source they also use some kind of function for their `onChange` field.

> Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LabelDropdown<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const LabelDropdown({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
    required this.list,
    this.onSelected,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final List<T> list;
  final Function(T value)? onSelected;

  @override
  _LabelDropdownState createState() => _LabelDropdownState();
}

class _LabelDropdownState<T> extends State<LabelDropdown> {
  late T _selected = widget.list[0];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(widget.label),
        DropdownButton<T>(
          value: _selected,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              _selected = value!;
              widget.onSelected!(value);
            });
          },
          items: widget.list
              .map(
                (value) => DropdownMenuItem<T>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value.toString()),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: LabelDropdown<String>(
              label: 'Label',
              list: const ['One', 'Two'],
              onSelected: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

> Error

```
E/flutter ( 3288): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '(String) => Null' is not a subtype of type '((dynamic) => dynamic)?'
E/flutter ( 3288): #0      _LabelDropdownState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:app/label_drop_down.dart:33
E/flutter ( 3288): #1      State.setState
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after hours of debugging, i found that my widget is stateful os this class is generic and i have passed generic as `LabelDropdown<String>` when using this class but i haven't used this generic to pass to its state class so instead of

```
  @override
  _LabelDropdownState createState() => _LabelDropdownState();
}

class _LabelDropdownState<T> extends State<LabelDropdown> {
```

should be like this

```
  @override
  _LabelDropdownState createState() => _LabelDropdownState<T>(); // added <T> when returning _LabelDropdownState
}

class _LabelDropdownState<T> extends State<LabelDropdown<T>> { // added <T> when pass type to state as LabelDropdown<T>
```